# ASP.NET Core HTTP Logger Middleware Results in " second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, entity-framework-core, middleware

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API that communicates with a SQL Server via Entity Framework Core and want to log all HTTP GET requests using a custom Middleware. Below is where I register the **DbContext** with a *scoped* life-time:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CustomDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConn")),
                optionsLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

While the middleware itself is (only showing relevant snippets):

```
public class HTTPTrafficLogger
    {
        private CustomDbContext DbContext;
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public HTTPTrafficLogger(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, CustomDbContext dbContext)
        {
            DbContext = dbContext;
            LogRequest(httpContext);
            await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
        }


        private void LogRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            try
            {
                StringBuilder requestContent = new StringBuilder();
                requestContent.AppendLine($"Protocol: {httpContext.Request.Protocol}");
                requestContent.AppendLine($"Method: {httpContext.Request.Method.ToUpper()}");
                requestContent.AppendLine($"Scheme: {httpContext.Request.Scheme}");
                requestContent.AppendLine($"PathBase: {httpContext.Request.PathBase}");
                requestContent.AppendLine($"Path: {httpContext.Request.Path}");

                foreach (var (headerKey, headerValue) in httpContext.Request.Headers)
                {
                    requestContent.AppendLine($"{headerKey}: {headerValue}");
                }

                AuthenticationTokenProperties authenticationTokenProperties = JWT.GetUserAuthenticationTokenProperties(httpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
                AuditDto HTTPRequestAuditDto = new AuditDto()
                {
                    UserEmailAddress = string.IsNullOrEmpty(authenticationTokenProperties.UserEmail) ? string.Empty : authenticationTokenProperties.UserEmail,
                    ActionName = httpContext.Request.Path.ToString(),
                    ModelName = "HTTPLoggerMiddleware",                    
                };

                // Add HTTPRequestAuditDto to the Database
                new AuditCore(DbContext, null).Add(HTTPRequestAuditDto);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                new SystemLogCore(DbContext, null).Add(ex, "", "HTTPTrafficLogger");
            }
        }
}
```

And then in **Program.cs** I add the custom middleware to the pipeline:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseHTTPTrafficLogger();
```

Although this does seem to work (i.e., the database logs the HTTP requests), I get the following error message in the output:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext.
```

When searching online for help regarding this issue, I found recommendations to set the life-time of DbContext to be transient, however, that did not solve the issue. When I tried to debug it, the behavior of the middleware is extremely odd, as what happens seems to be that the web server is not queueing multiple requests from one user correctly. The foreach loop exists abruptly and jumps back to the previous lines of code (i.e., **requestContent.AppendLine($"Protocol: {httpContext.Request.Protocol}");** and afterward). I also tried making the functions async and return Task but no avail. I think that the implementation of the logger is incorrect as there should be a queueing mechanism of a sort but would like to know if there is a simpler solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error will occur due to some `async` function accessing the DbContext instance not being awaited, "somewhere".

For something like an auditing service or logging service I would *not* inject a Scoped DbContext, but instead create A DbContext Factory class almogside the registered DbContext service capable of constructing a transient DbContext on demand.

For regular services/controllers etc. these can continue to accept an injected CustomDbContext, but for this HTTPTrafficLogger, and ideally other dependencies like it, you inject a CustomDbContextFactory. Then your LogRequest call would look more like:

```
private void LogRequest(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = CustomDbContextFactory.Create())
        {
            StringBuilder requestContent = new StringBuilder();
            requestContent.AppendLine($"Protocol: {httpContext.Request.Protocol}");
            requestContent.AppendLine($"Method: {httpContext.Request.Method.ToUpper()}");
            requestContent.AppendLine($"Scheme: {httpContext.Request.Scheme}");
            requestContent.AppendLine($"PathBase: {httpContext.Request.PathBase}");
            requestContent.AppendLine($"Path: {httpContext.Request.Path}");

            foreach (var (headerKey, headerValue) in httpContext.Request.Headers)
            {
                requestContent.AppendLine($"{headerKey}: {headerValue}");
            }

            AuthenticationTokenProperties authenticationTokenProperties = JWT.GetUserAuthenticationTokenProperties(httpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
            AuditDto HTTPRequestAuditDto = new AuditDto()
            {
                UserEmailAddress = string.IsNullOrEmpty(authenticationTokenProperties.UserEmail) ? string.Empty : authenticationTokenProperties.UserEmail,
                ActionName = httpContext.Request.Path.ToString(),
                ModelName = "HTTPLoggerMiddleware",                    
            };

            // Add HTTPRequestAuditDto to the Database
            new AuditCore(context, null).Add(HTTPRequestAuditDto);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        try
        {
            using(var context = CustomDbContextFactory.Create())
            {
                new SystemLogCore(context, null).Add(ex, "", "HTTPTrafficLogger");
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {   // Couldn't log the exception so Trace out to registered fallback output.
            Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The key difference here is rather than accepting and storing a reference to a shared DbContext, we would accept a DbContextFactory class and use that to create a scoped DbContext to serve our needs in isolation from any other shared instance. The DbContext is provided by a "Create()" call, and scoped within a `using` block. We can pass this instance through to other methods, but ideally the decision to commit the changes should remain in the scope where it was created, so methods that we might pass the DbContext to should not call `SaveChanges`, only the code that calls a Create before the scope ends.  Note that in the `catch` block we should create a newly scoped DbContext rather than wrap the whole try/catch within a scope. The reason for this is that the failure could be with writing the previous entities to the DbContext and erroring on a `SaveChanges` call. If we use the same DbContext instance for the `catch` block, that would almost certainly fail as well since the DbContext instance is "poisoned" with invalid data that cannot be saved. Any exception with saving the caught exception details should also be caught and handled to avoid a potential crash due to a logging issue.

Additionally, code like this:

```
new AuditCore(context, null).Add(HTTPRequestAuditDto);
```

... sends off red flags. The whole point of dependency injection is to *not* have instances new'd up inline. AuditCore should either be an abstract base class of HTTPTrafficLogger (and other auditing classes) or a dependency that is itself injected. Based on that this class appears to just be wrapping code to write the DTO to DB, I would be leaning to this being base class functionality. In that case the whole scoping of the DbContext should just be delegated down into the base "Add" method rather than within LogRequest.